# Unable to open phMyAdmin on Ubuntu 16. " Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed"

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, lampp

This is the elaborate message being displayed

> "phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

I found some links to edit the config.inc.php file under `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin` and edit the

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

as my password for root user is simply `'root'`
but still the same error persists.
I really need help upon this thing.
[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEYg4.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186588/connection-for-control-user-as-defined-in-your-configuration-failed-xampp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Can you Please try this code once.

Comment: I had tried that already and of no use.
There is one thing I noticed is that even after I start my lamp server and type localhost/ in the browser it does not open. I have to type localhost:8080/ only then it opens.
I dont know why is this so but just provided the info if it is helpful for someone to help me out with.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your config ist pointing to the wrong server or the port might be wrong.

Try setting the

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] ='hostname_of_database:port';
```

variable with the hostname and port of your mysql database.